# Headers of GridView should change dynamically

Tags: c#

I have a `CheckBoxList`, in which there are few items. I want these items to be headers of the `GridView`. And it should dynamically change with the changes in the items in the `CheckBoxList` Can someone kindly help me on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int checked_items = 0; checked_items < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; checked_items++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[checked_items].ToString());
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Thank for this reply. But now I wanted to know how to make all items in `ListBox` as headers of `GridView`..Kindly help.

Comment: simply change the loop range and select the property name "Items".
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int checked_items = 0; checked_items < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; checked_items++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[checked_items].ToString());
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;